# How to listen for ALL "Checked" or "UnChecked" event when using the CheckBoxModel in ExtJS 4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In ExtJS 4, I'm using the CheckBoxModel in my grid.Panel along with a displayed count that shows the current number of records selected. I then update my selected records count by listening to the event when an individual record has been checked or unchecked then posting the selected array value. It works just fine when selecting individual records. However when I check the "ALL" checkbox which either selects or deselects all the records I can't seem to find the entry point for my listener for the click event, therefore my displayed records count does not update. Additionally there is no such "ALL" selected/unselected event for the CheckBoxModel.

Answer (score 3):

try adding selectionchange listener on CheckboxModel : Fired after a selection change has occurred.

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ruY5h/)

Comment: good suggestion, logic can be tricky though - all select is the same if you hit the ALL box or the last remaining box - which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks MMT. I will test out your suggestion!

Comment: @user1110938 If it worked, don't forget to select it (check mark on the left) so others will know.

Comment: A minor improvement: sm.getSelection().length can be replaced by selected.length. No need to pass though the entire selectionModel.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I found myself also needing to bind some functions to the selectall and deselectall operations on the grid. My solution to this was to extend the `checkboxmodel` selection model so that I can attach `selectall` and `deselectall` listeners that fire at the correct time. The easiest way to do this was something like the following.

Firstly declare your new model and make sure it extends the checkboxModel

```
Ext.define('My.selection.CheckboxModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',
  onHeaderClick: function (headerCt, header, e) {
    if (header.isCheckerHd) {
      e.stopEvent();
      var me = this, isChecked = header.el.hasCls(Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-hd-checker-on');
      me.preventFocus = true;
      if (isChecked) {
        me.deselectAll(); // Pass true as a parameter to prevent selectionchanged and select events firing
        me.fireEvent('deselectall', me);
      }
      else {
        me.selectAll(); // Pass true as a parameter to prevent selectionchanged and select events firing
        me.fireEvent('selectall', me);
      }
      delete me.preventFocus;
    }
  }
});
```

Then on your grid add the following `selModel` to the configuration object:

```
  selModel: Ext.create('My.selection.CheckboxModel', {
    checkOnly: true, // you can add whatever normal configuration properties you want here
    listeners: {
      selectall: function () { console.log('selectAll'); },
      deselectall: function () { console.log('deselectAll'); }
    }
  }),
```

Its worth noting that the `selectionChanged` and `select` listeners on the grid and rows will also fire unless you pass true into the `selectall` and `deselectall` calls in the extended selection model.